# Airplane Mode won't turn off in Windows 10

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10

I have built my own PC with an i3. I have owned it for about a year and decided to install Windows 10. I noticed extremely slow internet speeds and then realised that Airplane Mode was on.

It wasn't greyed out, but as soon as I try to turn it off, it just turns back on again!

Any ideas?